# TAILS Virtual Machine Blank Screen On Boot

Tags: boot, virtualbox, tails

I've recently downloaded a copy of the TAILS 3.1 64-bit ISO image, burned it onto a disc and created a virtual machine through Oracle. At first glance, the virtual machine is running normally. The machine boots up into its initial options, giving you the option of recovery mode and normal TAILS -- before booting up into the actual Operating System where the 'Welcome to Tails' options screen is presented. When `start tails` is selected, the system continues to boot. On a normal functioning virtual machine, this would boot to the desktop (or an installation window, I haven't gotten that far yet so I don't know.)

On Oracle Virtual Machine, there is a black screen. There are no errors, or any information detailing what went wrong or what is going on -- just a blank screen. If anyone has any idea what this is, or how to solve the problem, it would be greatly appreciated. I have attempted to remove the VM from Oracle, and create a new one multiple times now, however the same problem is encountered each time.

Comment: Why are you burning it onto a disk when you are using a virtual machine? You can just point to the iso from your vm settings

Answer (score -1):

Disable VT-x/AMD-V acceleration (VM Settings, System, Acceleration)

It worked for me. It makes it slower (of course) but at least the graphics work. I have no idea why.

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem. Try adding `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the boot up edit menu.